# RegEx ignoring string values in encased in (brackets); and removing mark when input box is cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, search

I need your help,

1. The following JavaScript code below works to find a given match in the UL LI list and compares it to that of the input box. My question is two fold though, while it works, it seems to ignore any values that are encased by any brackets and;
2. The code seems to leave the search results (matches) still highlighted, even if the input box is cleared. The mark tags should be removed if the user is not searching for anything.

How can the code be modified so as to accommodate the two above conditions?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4TMC/4/

The code in question:

```
$("#refdocs").keyup(function(){

    var search = $(this).val();

    $("#refdocs_list li").each(function(){

        var val = $(this).text();

        if (val.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0 && search.length) {
            //$(this).addClass("selected");
            $(this).html(val.replace(RegExp("("+search.replace(/[\-$*{}()]/g,"\\$1")+")","ig"), "<mark>$1</mark>" ));   
        }
        else {

            $(this).removeClass("selected");      
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: You should post your markup here so that it is preserved for future visitors to SO. EDIT: your code seems to be working fine in FF. What are you testing in? (Chrome I'll bet). Wait, the item beginning with XAF doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't seem to reproduce your problems on Chrome.

Comment: Code has to be IE 10-11 compatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex isn't perfect just yet. You aren't replacing/escaping sqare brackets (`[]`), nor are you properly escaping any backslashes that might have been entered. I've set up [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CdjG7/2)
All I had to do to get it working was add a listener to handle mouse input events, and change the regex a tad:

```
//add this, change triggers when focus is lost, though, but handles empty fields
$("#refdocs").on('change', function()
{
    if (this.value == '')
        $("#refdocs_list li").each(function()
        {
            this.innerHTML = $(this).text();
        });
    else
        $(this).trigger('keyup');//run keyup handler if required

});
```

I've also noticed that, for one of the list items (XAF-2014-123456), your code fails to match `XAF` if the user input is in upper-case. That's because of your `if` condition:

```
if (val.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0 && search.length)
{//val.toLowerCase() -> also lowerCase the user input to ensure same case!
```

I've simply changed it to:

```
if (val.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) >= 0 && search.length)
{//lower-case to lower-case comparison, XAF and xaf both work now.
```

And now for the regex:

```
search.replace(/[-\\$*{}()[]]/g,"\\$1")
```

Notice how I moved the `-` to the front of the character-class. That's simply so that it doesn't need escaping.
Next, to filter out any backslashes that might have been put in by the user, I match a `\\` (an escaped backslash matches a literal `\`).
The rest of the character class is pretty much the same, but right near the end (the closing `]`), I've also added `[]`, to match square brackets. Normally, you'd escape them, but in this case, there is no ambiguity. Compare this:

```
/ambi[a-z[]0-9]/g
```

Here, there are a number of ways to interpret the regex: a char class of `a-z`+ `0-9` and `[]` literals, or a malformed pattern, with a character class of `a-z[`, a digit and a trailing `]`... However, `[{}[]]` is clearly a char-class that matches either curly or square brackets. If you want to play it safe, though, adding backslashes doesn't make any difference:

```
/[-\\$*{}()\[\]]/g
```

***Update***
Though this isn't something you were looking for: you commented you wanted to support IE10. IE has, since IE9, slowly but surely been conforming more and more to the standard, upheld by other browsers. Therefore, it's perfectly do-ably and pretty easy to write your code in a X-browser compatible way whilst maintaining X-browser compatibility.
It's not a big secret that I don't really like jQ (I find it bulky, slow and used *way* more than it should). So I've gone ahead and put together [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eae48/), which shows you a VanillaJS approach of what you're trying to do. It's still a tad rough around the edges, but you should be able to get this up and running in no time.

In this code, I've used *"clever"* (as in efficient) techniques such as a closure/IFFE (to store the DOM references, avoiding too many DOM lookups), and event delegation. Google these terms and work out how this code ticks. If you want to, that is. I promise you though: it's worth it, you'll find that most of the jQ code out there is quite ghastly.
Anyway, for those of you that care: here's the code:

```
(function(refdoc)
{
    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('#refdocs_list li'),
        wrapper = document.querySelector('#refdocs_list'),
        classPattern = /\bselected/,
        callback = function(e)
        {
            var i;
            for (i=0;i<listItems.length;++i)
                listItems[i].innerHTML = listItems[i].textContent;
            if (!this.value)
                return e;
            for (i=0;i<listItems.length;++i)
                if (listItems[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.value.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                    listItems[i].innerHTML = listItems[i].textContent.replace(new RegExp("("+this.value.replace(/[-\\$*{}()[]]/g,"\\$1")+")","ig"), "<mark>$1</mark>" );
        };
    wrapper.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        var i, t = (e = e || window.event).target || e.srcElement;
        if (t.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li')
        {
            for (i=0;i<listItems.length;++i)
            {
                listItems[i].innerHTML = listItems[i].textContent;
                listItems[i].className = listItems[i].className.replace(classPattern, '');
            }
            t.className += ' selected';
            refdoc.value = t.textContent;
        }
    }, false);
    refdoc.addEventListener('keyup', callback, false);
    refdoc.addEventListener('change', callback, false);
}(document.querySelector('#refdocs')));
```

All you need to do is put this in a `window.addEventListener('load', function(){ /*code here */}, false);` callback, and that's it.

Comment: Wow, that's thorough :)